# Is it possible to scope ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig settings to just your library?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, servicestack

I'm writing a custom library that uses [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) internally.  Other libraries that consume mine may also use ServiceStack.Text.

I want to change some `JsConfig` options (specifically date handling), but, like any good citizen, I don't want my modifications of those values to cause side effects for my consumer.

Unfortunately `JsConfig` is a static class, so its settings are static, and would bleed to other consumers of ServiceStack in the same AppDomain I believe.  That's an undesired behavior.

Is there some way to scope my configuration changes to just my calls to the `JsonSerializer`?

**Update**

I do realize there is the `JsConfig.Reset` method, unfortunately if the caller has customized it already, that would be lost.

I could save values and restore them, but I would have to synchronize access to the serializer, which also kind of defeats the purpose.

Hopefully there is something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This functionality was missing in ServiceStack.Text so I added a [pull request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/pull/253) for it.

Basically now if you wanted to scope your config settings you can use the following syntax:

```
using(var config = JsConfig.With(new Config { DateHandler = ... }))
{
}
```

And the values will no longer be set once the using block goes out of scope, its `ThreadStatic` as well so won't affect other threads.

Comment: @mythz Is it possible to add an array of DateTimeFormat? I need to handle more than one DateTimeFormat. Exactly the same that this code does JsConfig<DateTime?>.DeSerializeFn = str =>
   {
    if (str == null) return null;
    return DateTime.ParseExact(str, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
   };

Comment: @Paul_Tyng Is it possible to add an array of DateTimeFormat? I need to handle more than one DateTimeFormat.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility I've though of is just using a custom type internal to my library as the root object to serialize, and then specifying the `JsConfig` values specifically for that.

```
internal class MyInternalObject { }

JsConfig<MyInternalObject>.DateHandler = ...
```

I'm not sure if the root configuration values propagate down to child objects in the serialization, but easy enough to test.

Comment: Unfortunately `DateHandler` isn't on the generic version of this type, so this won't work.