# How can I change the JSON date serialization format for as single service in ServiceStack 3?

Tags: c#, servicestack-bsd

I have a number of legacy services in a ServiceStack 3 based middleware application which use the default date serialization format for JSON.  The issue is that this is not human readable for debugging.

I would like a new service that is being tested to have human readable dates, which the ISO8061 format can do.

How can I change, for ServiceStack 3, the JSON date serialization format for a single service or on a service by service basis?   I don't want to have to revalidate the consumers for all legacy services with a new date format.

....

Note:  I have found an answer for ServiceStack 4, but the option to create a ResponseScope on an HttpResult does not seem to exist in ServiceStack 3.

Comment: What have you tried so far..? What's your current output and what's your expected output?

Comment: @GeoffJames the question is specific. SS3 doesn't use the ISO8601 format that's become a standard. There was no date standard back then. An early attempt by Microsoft used a unix timestamp enclosed in some weird tags to prevent deserialization as an integer. The OP is asking how to make SS3 return ISO8601

Comment: I know how to set `JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601` in the global config.  Unfortunately, this would affect all legacy services requiring them to be revalidated.   I would like to control the JSON date serialization (or better yet, the entire JSON config) on a service by service basis.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- Thats fair enough, thank you. But I ask just so we might be able to see some examples of the ISO8061 standard, and what the OP has already tried doing in order to get round this issue?

Comment: @GeoffJames ISO8601 is a very well known standard.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ looking at the [source](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/e600c8ad7ee4593174f255838a0abf04abbe19ce/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs#L200), I see you can create a JsConfigScope to limit changes. Googling for JsConfigScope returns SO questions [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844796/is-it-possible-to-scope-servicestack-text-jsconfig-settings-to-just-your-library) that show how to use a JsConfigScope

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source of JsConfig](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/e600c8ad7ee4593174f255838a0abf04abbe19ce/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs#L200) and [similar SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844796/is-it-possible-to-scope-servicestack-text-jsconfig-settings-to-just-your-library) I see that you can use a JsConfigScope to limit the scope of Json settings. Perhaps you can write something like :

```
using(var config = JsConfig.With(dateHandler=JsonDateHandler.ISO8601))
{
    ...
}
```